# DNS request timed out

Tags: dns-zone, dns-hosting

I have a website running on Ubuntu 18.10 and apache 2.4 with SSL certificate registred using Letsencrypt and my DNS record is properly configured for my domain (www.shaheer.ga) on my hosting DNS Management section.

two days ago, my ISP has changed the default DNS Server to ClouDNS (10.20.30.40).

After this, my website stop working on default settings and now it will need user to change his default DNS to another DNS such as (8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1). If the user does this my website will start to work again.

This issue is appear in two error messages :

1- On Chrome (Android) : This site can't be reached ERR_CONNECTION_REFUED

2- On Chrome (Windows) : This site can’t be reached DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

nslookup -debug command shows:

```
    C:\Users\Alaa>nslookup -debug shaheer.ga
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        40.30.20.10.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  10.IN-ADDR.ARPA
        ttl = 86400 (1 day)
        primary name server = 10.IN-ADDR.ARPA
        responsible mail addr = (root)
        serial  = 0
        refresh = 28800 (8 hours)
        retry   = 7200 (2 hours)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)

------------
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.20.30.40

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

I already tries to create a DNS Zone for my domain on ClouDNS but this didn't help

Do you have any Idea why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Your domain looks good, that's not the problem. The problem appears to be that the name server you're using doesn't respond (correctly) . If that is the one your ISP assigns via DHCP, then contact them, as that is something you as an end-user can't fix.